# How to keep similar content and themes across an entire website

Tags: html, web

Say I want a web site with about 20 different pages. How should I go about building it so I can have the same content like a navbar and footer across all pages without having to copy and paste edits into each and every html file when something changes?

edit: I'm basically trying to figure out how to do Jade's include without installing Jade

Answer (score 1):

That depends entirely on how you build it.  If you are using a content management system (such as WordPress or Joomla) this is the inherent behavior.  Header/footer content, and other areas depending on your use of widgets, etc. will automatically display the same content on every page.  This content is easy to update site-wide in one location.  Content management systems excel in this area.

If you are building the site from static files, and you are using a scripting language of some kind (such as PHP, ASP, etc) the use of includes would be a good option.  Simply call the repeated block of code wherever you'd like to insert it on each page.

For example, if using PHP, you have a file that contains your legal text in the footer called `footer_legal.php`.   Anytime you wished to include this content, you simply add the line `include('footer_legal.php');` and the insertion happens.

Answer (score 0):

What you're referring to is called templating and bootstrapping. There are various templating engines out there. It also depends on which server-side language you're running, as others said you maybe running PHP, NodeJS, C or something else, depends on your choice. The essential part is that you'll have separate files called templates (eg. .HTML, .EJS, .PHP, etc) for each element that repeats across different pages ( footer, header, content) and then you call that template where you want it.